# How to use compareToIgnoreCase

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I was given an example on how to alphabetically sort my Actor objects in an array.

```
public class AlphaSortingExchange
{
 public static void main(String[ ] args)
 {
         String[ ] names = {"joe", "slim", "ed", "george"};
         sortStringExchange (names);
         for ( int k = 0;  k < 4;  k++ )
            System.out.println( names [ k ] );
  }

  public static void sortStringExchange( String  x [ ] )
  {
        int i, j;
        String temp;

        for ( i = 0;  i < x.length - 1;  i++ )
        {
            for ( j = i + 1;  j < x.length;  j++ )
            { 
                     if ( x [ i ].compareToIgnoreCase( x [ j ] ) > 0 )
                      {                                             // ascending sort
                                  temp = x [ i ];
                                  x [ i ] = x [ j ];    // swapping
                                  x [ j ] = temp;

                       }
               }
         }
  }
}
```

I am only allowed to follow this sort of format in sorting my array. NetBeans is not liking the "compareToIgnoreCase" statement in my code, giving the error

> "cannot find symbol: method compareToIgnoreCase(Actors) location class
>   Actors"

. Below is my sorting function.

```
public static void sortActors(Actors actors[]) {

    int i, j;
    Actors temp;

    for (i = 0; i < actors.length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < actors.length; j++)
        {
            if (actors[i].compareToIgnoreCase(actors[j]) > 0)
            {
                temp = actors[i];
                actors[i] = actors[j];
                actors[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my object array and an example of an object in the array. Like I said before, I can only use compareToIgnoreCase. I am at a loss at how to use this function

```
private static void createActorsList() {

    Actors[] actors = new Actors[Constants.NUMBER_OF_ACTORS];

    Actors ladyViolet = new Actors();
    ladyViolet.setName("Lady Violet");
    ladyViolet.setDialogue("dialogue");
    ladyViolet.setHappiness(0);
    ladyViolet.setHealth(100);
    actors[Constants.VIOLET] = ladyViolet;
}
```

Any help or solution would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Actor` class doesn't have a `compareToIgnoreCase` method. You probably mean to call the method on one of the class's fields, e.g.,

```
if (actors[i].getName().compareToIgnoreCase(actors[j].getName()) > 0)
```

If the method needs to be on the `Actor` class, you'd have to write your own implementation:

```
public int compareToIgnoreCase(Actor actor) {
    return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(actor.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved my problem because I actually had the function getName() in my Actor class.